# Correct capitalization of words beginning with "e-" (for "electronic")

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations, neologisms

What is the correct capitalization of words beginning with "e-" (like e-mail or e-learning or e-assessment) when used in a title? Is it "E-Learning" or "E-learning" or even "e-Learning"?

To clarify: This question is not about *hyphenation* of such words (there are lots of other questions about that topic), but only about *capitalization*, e. g., in titles or at the beginning of a sentence. For the argument's sake, let's assume the words *are* to be hyphenated. ("Email" is a trivial answer.)

Comment: At least some common terms have already dropped the hyphen, such as *email*. So, where there is no ambiguity, people are already accustomed to seeing a sentence starting with *Email*. I do not know if a single correct way has been agreed upon yet.

Comment: There is no "correct".

Comment: You may also want to consider the term "eLearning". A form which has no doubt been popularized due to Apple.

Comment: @Bjorn: Nope, the question is specifically about capitalising *e-* words **with** hyphens, not about whether *e-learning* itself needs a hyphen.

Comment: @Hugo: You're right Hugo. I got so caught up on how to write the word itself that I completely forgot the OP is only considering hyphenated versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be some exceptions, but in titles I would generally capitalise as *E-Learning*.

The first page of [Google Books results](https://www.google.com/search?q=e-learning&tbm=bks&tbo=1&oq=e-lear):

- 6 x *e-Learning*
- 4 x *E-Learning*
- 0 x *E-learning*

This one page is a too small sample, but you can check a number of books and see how it has been used in various places.

If there's a clear accepted form for any given *e-* word, then use that. Otherwise, I think the key is to to pick a style and use it consistently.

Comment: Hugo, I fear Ngram may not be a very adequate tool for analysing usage of what is still a fairly recent term. If you run the Ngram again for the period of 1990-2008, the results differ drastically. While apparently results for the period 2000-2008 are less reliable owing to subtle changes in the corpus composition, they do indicate that both "E-learning" and "e-Learning" became much more popular after 2000. I think we can't draw any definitive conclusion from Ngram on this matter and that your advice to "pick a style and use it consistently" is the best thing one could do.

Comment: @Bjorn: You're right. I've removed the misleading Ngram.

Comment: @ Hugo: Did come come across the form "eLearning" at all? This form (lowercase e followed by a capitalized form of the word) is often used for eBooks and has no doubt gained some general popularity due to Apple's iPod, iPad, iCloud, iEverything.

Comment: @Bjorn: I didn't even consider *eLearning*, because this question is specifically about capitalising *e-* words **with** hyphens, not about whether *e-learning* needs a hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

Computer mediated messages are now written as *emails*. When the word begins a sentence, or appears in a title, there would appear to be no reason not to write it as *Emails*. It’s too soon to say whether the other *e* words will go the same way. *Elearning* might, but there are obvious problems with a word like *eassessment*, whether with *e* or *E*. In general, however, I’d say it would be wise to follow current orthographic conventions and use the upper case letter where it would normally be required, provided doing so does not create difficulty for the reader. So, assuming hyphenation, *E-learning*, *E-assessment*, *E-reader* and so on.

Comment: I think the question is about what is best when a lowercase-e word like *e-learning* occurs in a context that expects a capitalized word, like a title or the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You're right. I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: The question specifically says the hyphen is still present: in a title, how do we capitalise *e-learning, e-assessment, e-commerce, e-petition, e-reader*, e-tc?

Comment: @Hugo Amended again.

Answer (score 0):

The *Microsoft Manual of Style, 4th Edition* (used for technical documentation) recommends avoiding *e-* forms of words, unless necessary. For example, it recommends using words *message* and mail instead of *email*--the context should make the medium clear.

When it is appropriate to use an *e-* word, it recommends to use a hyphen and to capitalize it like any other hyphenated word *(exception: email is not hyphenated)*.

### Examples

> E-commerce is a very lucrative business model.
>
> Do you like e-commerce?
>
> How to Succeed at E-Commerce (title capitalization)

### Watch out for non-native speakers

*E-* words are not easily translated and may be confusing to non-native English speakers. So if you are writing for a global audience, it's usually better to avoid *e-* words, even if it means using more words.

Comment: _E-_ words are not easily translated? Well, that at the very least depends on your target language, and on the particular term in question. If you’re translating into another Germanic language (and to some extent even a Romance one, or any number of other languages), for example, you can simply use the prefix _e-_ in the target language. The most common word in Mandarin for _e-commerce_, for instance, is “e商务” or “e商业”. They’re no more difficult to translate than any other randomly found lexeme in a language.